# SceneKit node rotation applied during viewDidLoad has no effect

Tags: scenekit

I have a SceneKit scene comprising a reference node from a `.dae` file (exported from Blender) and various cameras and lights added directly in the Scene Editor. For the reference node to appear with the correct orientation in the editor, it has a rotation applied to it (-90, 0, 0). This doesn't carry over to the in-app view, so I have been successfully applying a rotation in a function called from `viewDidLoad()`.

Since a refactoring today, no rotation occurs. The code still attempts to apply the correction in the same way - this was just a tidy-up.

Various hacks do successfully rotate the node:

- Apply the rotation as an `SCNAction.rotateTo()` with a duration of zero, rather than `node.eulerAngles =`
- Arranging for the rotation to be applied at a later time (`Timer.scheduledTimer(...)`)

Both of which suggest there's a timing issue, that pre-refactor I wasn't hitting. Do SceneKit node rotations only take effect if the node has been rendered at least once? There's certainly some optimisation behind the scenes as even a delayed assignment to `node.eulerAngles` only has an effect on what is rendered if it causes a change in the value.

#### Edit:

Careful comparison of the before and after versions of code revealed a seemingly unimportant ordering change. In the original, I added some generated nodes (a sub-class of `SCNNode` with a plane using an `SKScene` as it's texture) *before* rotating the reference node (which worked). Post re-factor, that order had reversed. The nodes are siblings, not descendants, so I can't see why that should matter, unless than the SKScene-as-texture slows things down enough to avoid some optimisation?

Answer (score 1):

Generated the example game code and applying the rotation within viewDidLoad worked for both repeatForever and rotateBy calls, but the example code really doesn't do much.  Not sure that proves anything since the render loop is actually processed in its own thread.  Without seeing the code or how much is going on in your render loop, it's quite possible that your rotation commands are not always being processed since they are not being injected in the rendering queue thread.

As an alternative, rotate your model to the desired position in blender, then set Y-Up for Scenekit.  I'm not very good with Blender, so I saved some documentation on how to rotate, save, and export in Blender - I can post this if you need it.  Then process the model for Y-Up with this command line.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/scntool --convert fighter0.dae --format c3d --output out.dae --force-y-up --force-interleaved --look-for-pvrtc-image

Not sure how far a long you are, but I battled this for a long time and found that it worked better for me if my blender model is set to the correct rotation from the beginning and will also preview correctly in XCode.  At some point, you may be doing some rotation or SCNLookat and my models were always off.  There might have been a simpler way to correct them, but why do the extra math when it can be set in the state you'd like from the beginning.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Some useful reminders in there, thanks. Since it doesn't directly address the question of why SceneKit chooses not to apply a requested rotation, I am inclined to leave the question unanswered for a while longer.